# Unable to see any Wireless networks

Tags: wifi

I am running into problems with my wireless card on Debian Jessie.
It uses the wl driver.

dmesg shows this error:

```
ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

I am unable to see any networks with NetworkManager on the GUI.

rfkill shows wlan0 is neither hardblocked nor softblocked.

iwlist says that the interface does not support scanning.

output from iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

output from ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f1:a1:cb:2b:3b  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the arch linux forums. It is a bizzare problem with the wl driver on Dell xps machines. Somehow, I had pressed Ctl+Prtsc, which disabled the driver through the hardware and made the wireless deice disappear. To solve, press Ctl+Prtsc again. It may take several tries before it works.